# Download folders from dev server to local drive

Tags: powershell

I am developing a .net web application on a local environment. I have a dev server that the application is installed on. Within the web application on the dev server I have four folders that I dont have locally and that are controlled by another application.

In my day to day development I require the four folders on local PC. I would like to automate the process of pulling the folders from the dev server to my local drive, so I can keep thing in sync. Ideally something like this

Run file from main folder (be it a bat file, powershell, some sort of job, open to recommendations)
Download 4 folders supplied to it. 
First download bring everything down, from them on only pull the changes

Not sure where to start with achieving this but would appreciate any help would with. I know there are apps out there that do something like this but would like to give a go writing something to do this before I resort to using one of them.

Comment: Anyone that could help me out with this or even a starting point?

Answer (score 1):

if those folders ale somewhere in local network (and you have access from dev server there) then batch file running robocopy should suit your needs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

It is really great tool. Additionally you could have to add "net use" command to that batch (it depends on user rights).

Hope that helps.

Comment: They arent on the local network but are on a web server. I could include a step in the process to map a drive to the server. Would that work?

Comment: Only if you could access shares from that server using Windows explorer (you could have vpn connection for instance). If servers are located on separate networks (accross Internet), then quite simple solution is to make those four folders available through ftp and create batch script with wget task to synchronize folders on local drive.